# Not able to add profile header and navigation menu back to the Napili template

Tags: napili, lightning-community

I removed the navigation menu and page header which was available by default in my template, now, I am not able to bring it back. any idea why?

Comment: How you removed these things?

Comment: Are you trying to customize the napili theme?

Comment: Please check here : In Community Builder, click Community builder settings icon on the left, click General, and then select Hide header region and navigation. Choosing this option hides the default header image, the search box, the community menu, and user profile navigation menu on all the pages in your community.

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty i am not trying to customize, i have created a custom theme and used it in place of default theme, i removed the existing nav menu, and i am not able to find else where

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 i removed it by click close button on top right of the navigation menu component

Comment: @PrabhatKumar As i am using custom theme i dont have that option, it shows  only in default theme

Comment: Screenshots are very useful when asking community related issues, as it is template based and will help other orient you into what options to check